# to share something eatable with someone

Tags: idiomatic-language, ambiguity

If I wish to eat some of the chocolate my friend is eating. Can I say:

> 1. Give me a bite.
> 2. Share me a bite.
> 3. Let me take a bite.
> 4. Can you share a bite?

**Important: Does it have any taboos meaning too?**

Comment: You forgot *"Can I have a bite?"* and *"What about a bite?"* and *"Would you let me have a bite?"* and *"Let's have a bite to eat"* and...

Comment: One potential taboo might be that "a bite" sounds like you're going to put your mouth on a large shared chocolate bar. If you ask for "a piece" or "a bit" instead of "a bite," then that implies that you'd like him to break off a bit of chocolate for you so you are not both eating from the same candy bar.

Comment: Another potential taboo is that if your friend's eating a chocolate ***bar***, you taking a bite from it would be as risky as drinking from the same bottle, or sharing a cigarette, in terms of transferring the Covid virus.

Answer (score 2):

Give me a bite -- grammatically correct, sounds a little like you are demanding a bite.

Share me a bite -- this is not correct English. 'Share' does not take a direct object like 'give' does.

Let me take a bite -- grammatically correct, a little awkward. It sounds like you're saying that refusing to 'let' the speaker take a bite is somehow unexpected.

Can you share a bite -- grammatically correct, again a little awkward.

Ways I might expect it to be phrased:

> May I please have a bite?

> Can I have a bite?

> Would you please let me have a bite? (or without please, which just makes it more polite)

Answer (score 2):

1. **“Give me a bite.”** This sounds impolite because an [imperative statement](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/imperative-sentence-examples.html) is very often a command but adding a "please" at the end, will soften the tone.
2. **“Share me a bite.”** this is understandable but not idiomatic.  The speaker is asking someone to share his or her food. A more idiomatic request would be:   "*Can I ask for **a bit of** your chocolate, please?*", "**Can I have** a piece / some of your chocolate, please?", or more informally “***How about sharing** a bite [with me]*?” or even: "**Spare** me a bite.”

- *a bit* = a small piece
  *[spare](https://www.lexico.com/definition/spare)* (verb) = give something to someone

3. “**Let me take a bite.**” Depending on context and tone of voice, this could be very impolite as the speaker wants to *taste* somebody's food without asking permission.
4. “**Can you share a bite?**” This is an acceptable way of forming a request but sounds a bit peculiar. It's as if the speaker is looking at the friend's chocolate greedily.

Other alternative ways of asking someone to share a piece of their food are:

Among friends and family:

- That [*chocolate*] looks delicious.
  Let's have a taste. (very informal)
  Give us a piece. (very informal)
  Will you let me have a taste [*of that* [*chocolate*]], please?
  Could I just have a *tiny* tiny bit? (As you say this, show how small a piece you want with your fingers)
  [image]
- *[taste](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/taste_1)* = a small amount of food or drink to see what flavour it has